# What is parsing/applying /etc/fstab entries

Tags: linux, systemd, fstab, systemd-mount

According to [manual](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd-remount-fs.service.8.en.html) I thought that `systemd-remount-fs.service` is responsible for parsing and applying `/etc/fstab` entries. So I tried to test it: I removed `ExecStart` part (`ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-remount-fs`) and rebooted the system. After booting and logging in I still had fstab entries in `mount`.

And now I am wondering if it's the kernel's job itself? How can I do a job before fstab entries get mounted (in case it's kernel's job)?

Comment: Thanks for MC68020 for pointing me in the right direction, regarding the second part of my question, [this comment](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/15890#issuecomment-632890738) on github is a good start for anyone interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel usually mounts the root filesystem at the very end of the boot sequence.
It is usually mounted readonly and irrespective of whatever mount option set as part of the `/etc/fstab` file.

Control is then, given to the init system.

As specified in the manual you linked to, `systemd-remount-fs.service` :

> ignores normal file systems and only changes the root
> file system (i.e. /), /usr/, and the virtual kernel API file systems
> such as /proc/, /sys/ or /dev/.

You can also read that this service :

```
is usually pulled in by systemd-fstab-generator
```

[**systemd-fstab-generator**](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd-fstab-generator.8.en.html) is in fact responsible for instantiating the initial mount of filesystems according to fstab entries.

> This will instantiate mount and swap units as necessary.

It is therefore normal that if you inhibit the automatic execution of systemd-remount-fs.service and reboot, you'll still see your filesystems mounted according to the `/etc/fstab` entries.